# Intellisense not working with imports in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, intellisense, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

When using javascript (es2015) imports the Intellisense seems to be broken.

When I am working in the same file, VSC autosuggests the methods from the object with the correct JSDoc information.

[image]

However, when importing the Class in another file, the Intellisense seems to be completely broken ( david.david, wtf? ).

[image]

Do I need to adjust any settings in Visual Studio Code to get this working? I tried adjusted my jsconfig file to es2015 imports and es6 as but that didn't work.

My jsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6"
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a lot of issues using es2015 in Code. Ended up scrapping it and went back to atom...

Comment: I have seem to found the issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/61 it's a known bug

Answer (score 11):

Because you are using `export` without `default` you need to enable [`allowSyntheticDefaultImports`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

The same occurs with

```
import fs from 'fs';
import axios from 'axios';
```

And others.